# Comparison of two dates in if statement

Tags: apex, controller, date, error-messages

In my controller i try to compare two dates and if it tru return the error message.

```
Date Today = system.Today();
Date StartDateParsed = Date.parse(startdate);   
if(StartDateParsed <= Today){bring ERROR message}
```

the problem is when the conditional is true it works like it is false. In the debug it shows:

```
|DEBUG|StartdateP=2016-09-26 00:00:00Today=2016-09-26 00:00:00
```

Why it doen't work?

**Upd:**

```
date dt = system.Today();
String st = dt.format();
startDate = st; 

startDate = |DEBUG|startdate=9/26/2016
```

**Upd 2**
If i ran this code (And startDate < or = Today):

```
    if(StartDateParsed <= Today){ 
        System.debug ('True');
    } 
    else{
        System.debug('False');
    }
```

Debug is True

**Upd 3**
I have the another page messages that shows correctly:

```
if (context.Title == NULL){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please select the Title for Contact'));
        }
```

but the next code doen't shows the error message at all

```
if (context.SelectedType == 'Planned' && numberDaysDue >= 0){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please specify the future date'));
            system.debug('true');
        }
```

And the debug log says true. This Error message doesn't shows at all, but the rest messages shows fine.

**Upd 4**
VisualForce section Error messages:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="messages">
<apex:pageMessages />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

My save button:

```
<apex:commandButton id="save" value="Save" action="{!save}" style="padding: 5px;" status="nextActionStatus" reRender="messages,screens,buttons" rendered="{!Context.Type != NULL && Context.Contacts != NULL}"/>
```

I don't think that the proble is in my vf page, because the rest messages are shown correctly.

**Upd 5**

```
if (context.SelectedType == 'Planned' && StartDateParsed <= Today){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please specify the future date'));
        }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to share with us the `startDate` string?

Comment: @AdrianLarson added

Comment: @Viktor from where are you getting "startdate" value?
Meanwhile try this - Date startDateParsed = today - 5;
if(today > startDateParsed){ System.debug ('today is greater than startDateParsed');}
else{System.debug('why??');}

Comment: @mritzi Hi! Just try your code. The debug says why??. The string startdate is setup for system.Today() it is user inputtext.

Comment: Why do you think "it doesn't work"? That is really vague. It sounds like you might just be missing a `rerender` or something.

Comment: @AdrianLarson all of the rest ERROR messages works fine. but in this case i don't get the ERROR message, and i don't know why. Just try the below code: if(StartDateParsed <= Today){ 
    System.debug ('True');
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please specify the future date'));
   } 
   else{
    System.debug('False');
   } and it must show error message if the StartDateparsed = or < Today, but it doesn't

Comment: You're giving us virtually no context to work with... I can do the following with no problem so your issue is elsewhere: `system.assert(Date.parse('9/26/2016') <= Date.today());`.

Comment: if you just want to check the different between 2 dates then you can use `daysBetween(secondDate)` method https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm?search_text=date  Can you just give a try with this method? hope this will solve your problem

Comment: @Ratan Hi! Just implement your code, but the problem doesn't solved. Please see Upd 3

Comment: put debug on `context.SelectedType == 'Planned' && numberDaysDue >= 0` and check tis is giving true or false. if false then put debug on individual variable and check the fault

Comment: @Ratan, |DEBUG|Daysdue=0 AND |DEBUG|Type=Planned, This is true

Comment: ahh then issue with your page I guess. check if you are rerendering the `apex:pagemessage` tag or not ?

Comment: @Ratan, Please look at Upd 4 section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45918/discussion-between-ratan-and-viktor).

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear. From what I read in your question you expect 9/26/2016 <= 9/26/2016 to be false?? It is not, it is true as it is equals to. Maybe try restating your question without all of the extraneous detail. If your issue is with the page message, well you are not showing how you are creating it. Maybe post the entire code block for the date compare. Also, make sure you are not calling any action functions that then would cause the page message to be cleared.

Comment: @Eric, I expect that 9/26/2016 <= 9/26/2016 to be true. But it true! The problem is that if that expression is true the Error message doesn't shows. Other Errors appears correctly, but in this expression the error doesn't shows up.

Comment: @Viktor post up your code where you check the values and create the error

Comment: @Eric, Please see the Upd 5 section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why the message doesn't appear. But i'm find another way to make this work correctly.

```
//Create the list of string for the error messages
List<String> errors =new List<String>();
String allErrors ='';

//Make the condition for error massage appear
if (context.SelectedType == 'Planned' && StartDateParsed <= Today){

     //Add the message in to a list 
     errors.add('Please specify the future date');
}

//Create the string of errors for show up as extension
//Make sure you set escape="false" in apex:pageMessages section
if (!errors.isEmpty()){                
                    for (String val : errors) {
                            allErrors = allErrors + val + '<br/>';
                    }                
            throw new TaskSchedulerException(allErrors);
        }
```